# binding event handlers in prototype and still maintain reference to element

Tags: javascript, events, prototypejs

I want to be able to use a bound event handler in prototype and retain my "this" context.  But doing so seems to destroy the convenient default binding that prototype gives event handlers.

From the docs:

> The handler's context (this value) is set to the extended element being observed (even if the event actually occurred on a descendent element and bubbled up).

That's exactly what I want.  Once I bind the function to my own context, can I get access to this "element being observed" in any way?  I can't depend on e.element() to give me the observed element (it could be a child element):

```
initialize: function() {
     Event.observe('foo', 'click', this.addItem.bind(this));
},

...

addItem: function(e) {
   e.element() // -> clicked element, not necessarily observed element
}
```

I know that there's a bindAsEventListener, but it doesn't seem to be necessary here and I don't see how I can access the targeted element once the function is bound.

I also am aware that there's an e.currentTarget, but that doesn't work in IE, does it?

Answer (score 2):

When you use `.bind` your reference to the observed element via `this` is overwritten. If you have the following markup:

```
<div id="foo">
    I am the Foo
    <button id="bar">I am the Bar</button>
</div>
```

Without using `.bind` you can access the observed & firing elements like so:

```
function greenEggsAndHam (evt) {
    console.log('Observed Element: %o', this);
    console.log('Clicked Element: %o', $(evt.element()));
}
Event.observe('foo', 'click', greenEggsAndHam);
```

However, if you want to use a class method as the event handler, and thus need to use `.bind`, then the solution is to include the observed element's identifier as one of the arguments to the event handler when you first bind the event, like so:

```
var Test = Class.create({
    initialize: function() {
        Event.observe('foo', 'click', this.greenEggsAndHam.bind(this, 'foo'));
    },
    greenEggsAndHam: function (el, evt) {
        console.log('Observed Element: %o', $(el));
        console.log('Clicked Element: %o', $(evt.element()));
        console.log('Class reference: %o', this);
    }
});
var T = new Test();
```

That said, for sake of consistency I'd suggest you use `.bindAsEventListener` instead of `.bind`, and change your event handler to `function (evt, el) {` so that the event object is the first argument and the observed element the second.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem recently.  My answer was to wrap the function in another function that does the work you need.  I may have messed up the order but `curry` will add `this` to the args of the anonymous function and then you re-order from there.

```
initialize: function() {
  Event.observe('foo', 'click', 
    function(e,that) { that.addItem(e,this); }.curry(this)
    );
  },
addItem: function(evt, evtElm) {
  ...
  }
```